# How to create UI similar to file replace dialog in window 7 using C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I need to create a dialog that allows user to choose between several rather complex actions. I really like the usability of the windows 7 file replace dialog and I think it would suit my needs very well. Here's a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Is it possible to use the controls that were used for windows dialog? If not, how would you recommend creating UI similar to this dialog?

Comment: The OS supports this with Task dialogs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787471(VS.85).aspx. For managed code wrappers, see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Comment: @Mattias This is exactly what I was looking for! However, after some thought I realised that I need to support windows XP too, so sadly this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this could easily be done with a window containing a few labels for the text and three custom controls - with some images for the arrows and file icons - each of which changes their background image when the user mouses over them - and fires an event the window picks up on when they are clicked. Fairly standard WinForms stuff.

Is there a particular part of the process you need some extra help with? Like, for example, the mouse over?