# How to create a Windows Explorer style message box using C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, messagebox

Does anyone know how to create these fancy message boxes using .NET WinForms?
Can I do that with built-in features of .NET, or do I have to build it on my own or by using an external library?

I'd also like to customize the buttons and icons, obviously.

[image: Sample Message Box]

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599154/how-to-create-ui-similar-to-file-replace-dialog-in-window-7-using-c-sharp-window)

Comment: It is not a message box, it is a TaskDialog.  Not especially friendly to use in C#, do look for basic Google hits by querying "c# taskdialog".